# uploading image to server using php

Tags: php, javascript, html

in the following code ,i am trying to upload an image to server . there is a folder 'images ' on the server. whenever i am clicking the 'ok' button ...it gives an error " there is problem in uploading file"... where is the problem in my code?

html-----------------------------------------

```
     <form method="post" action="newproduct.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       Item Image:<input type="file" name= "photo" size="40" /> 
       Description:<textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="1"></textarea>
       <input name="submit" type="submit" value = "Submit" /> 
       </form>

php-------------------------------------------------------

$target = "images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

              $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
              $description =$_POST["description"];


//checking for empty values
if (empty($pic) || empty($description))
    {
     echo "Please enter all field values.";  
       }     
else
    {

              //Connecting to database server       

         //Connecting to database


        //INSERT Query
        $SQLstring = "INSERT INTO items VALUES(null,'$pic' ,'$description')";
        $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
        or die ("<p> Unable to execute the query. </p>".
                "<p> Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect) . ":" . mysqli_error($DBConnect))."</p>";


               if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['name'], $target)) 
               {  
               echo "The file has been added to the directory"; 
                } 
               else 
                {  

                echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
                } 

                mysqli_close($DBConnect);
        }           


?>
```

Comment: File had been uploaded or not ?

Comment: @dev yes folder 'images' already existed

Answer (score 0):

you can't do that... you don't update a photo like that in Javascript... (with ajax..)
It is not going to work like that...

But... you can fake this...

You have to submit that post somehow...

You have several solutions: use a flash to fake upload ajax or an iframe..

You can also use jQuery .. he will do all the stuff for you..

Here are some demo & download links:

- http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/
- http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/
- http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

If you want to move the uploaded file you have to move the "tmp_name" with the new name.. like

```
 if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $path.$_FILES['photo']['name'])) 
     echo 'CANNOT MOVE {'.$_FILES['photo']['name'].'}' . PHP_EOL;
```

When you upload your file, apache takes care of it and by default is in /tmp (if you use linux... I don't know in windows case)..

P.S: for your script's performance you should use ' ' instead of " " for strings.. when you use " " PHP is checking every " "(string) for variables == more operations to do.. and ' ' are skipped

Comment: i did without ajax in the upper code, now its not giving empty values error but its showing that there is an error in uploading file?

Comment: @Ayman in this case you have to move the tmp file.. not 'name'.. I think it's 'tmp_name'... I will edit my post...

Answer (score 0):

The images folder needs to have 777 permissions on it. By default the permissions are 655, and PHP does not have permissions to upload/move/copy a file outside the current folder it is in (subdirectories count as different folder)

Comment: how can i set this permission?

Comment: in your ftp client, right click the folder and choose "File/Manage Permissions"